# ZipKit and iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, gzip, unzip

I tried to use the ZipKit framework (http://bitbucket.org/kolpanic/zipkit/wiki/UsingZipKit) in the test application for iPad. I followed the "Traditional way" of the installation (as it is described on their page) with no success. Hope somebody can help me with it:

1/ I used *hg* to get sources
  2/ I build the *ZipKit* project (Release build)
  3/ After doing this there was created in the build folder the new *ZipKit.framework* folder
  4/ I have created a new test project for the iPad 3.2 (XCode 3.2.4)
  5/ I have drag&dropped the *ZipKit.framework* folder created in the step 3) into *Frameworks* section on my new test project
  6/ In *Targets* section I have created new *Copy File Build Phase* and I drag&drop the  *ZipKit.Framework* from *Frameworks* section to the new *Copy Files* folder.
  7/ Then I build and run the project.

The project cannot be even started, it is being closed after I press the project icon - so I must do something terribly wrong. In the console output I can see the error - it is pretty clear what is missing, but I do not know what to do with that... Might be some XCode expert or someone, who used the ZipKit can help me - this must some really stupid mistake I am doing...

There is the console output:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Frameworks/ZipKit.framework/Versions/A/ZipKit
  Referenced from: /Users/sten/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/3.2/Applications/3C51FC4F-0E85-48D2-BC68-D01ADD73DAE1/ZipExample.app/ZipExample
  Reason: image not found
Failed to launch simulated application: iPhone Simulator failed to find the process ID of com.yourcompany.ZipExample.
```

BTW - I have tried to run the *ZipKit Touch* example provided with the framework and it works perfectly...

Thanks a lot
BR
STeN

There is the screenshot of my test project - on the left side you can see the ZipKit.framework I drag&drop into my project:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go back and read it again.

The "traditional way" is *not* the right way to do this - Apple don't allow iOS applications with external frameworks like this - you want to link against the static library instead using the process described under "Static Library Target".

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! So all I was doing was wrong? Both the "Traditional way" and the "Better approach" are for MAC OS X and I should use the "Static Library Target" way? It will be nice to express this on build pages - it might be clear for someone more experienced then me... I have just spend 2 days on this:(( Thanks for the reply, STeN

Answer (score 1):

Is there a basic page which shows some simple code for inflating and deflating files and directories for ZipKit?

UPDATE:
I figured this out but it was a scavenger hunt:

```
NSString *filePath = [userDocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"newFile.zip"];

ZKFileArchive *archive = [ZKFileArchive archiveWithArchivePath:filePath];
[archive deflateDirectory:exportDirectory relativeToPath:nil usingResourceFork:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the Using ZipKit page to make it clear which ZipKit target should be used for what type of product.

Comment: You might also want to clarify the need to link against libz.dylib - its a bit hidden in some of the screen snaps.